# How to use ajax filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to filter out some values from an AJAX call. Here's what I have tried:

```
var year = 200908; // for example          
var resultArray = data.filter(function (a) {
    return a.proddate == year;
});

var firstTask = resultArray[0];
var lastTask = resultArray[resultArray.length - 1];
```

`data` is coming from `success` function in an ajax call. But I'm getting this error:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'
```

Here is a sample of the returned data:

```
"[{
    "tasknum":6,
    "dependtask":5,
    "jobname":"prc",
    "proddate":"200908",
    "activity":"Pr‌​elim",
    "groupname":"CNSPROD-EST",
    "parametername":"n/a",
    "parametervalue":"n/a"
}]"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: error is already telling you what the issue is, `data` is an object but `filter()` is an array function. Post data sample

Comment: "[{"tasknum":6,"dependtask":5,"jobname":"prc","proddate":"200908","activity":"Prelim","groupname":"CNSPROD-EST","parametername":"n/a","parametervalue":"n/a"}]"

Answer (score 0):

First, try doing a `console.log` on `data` and verify what exactly you're retrieving. `filter` only works on arrays so this would work:

```
var resultArray = [1,2,3].filter(function(a) {
    return a > 2;
});
```

But this will not:

```
// "Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'"
var resultArray = {1: true, 2: true, 3: true}.filter(function() { ... });
```

Comment: my obj looks like this : [[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]]

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that you're receiving the correct object? [Your code runs fine right here](http://jsfiddle.net/6esm3/)

Comment: I tried all three ways but either gives me null error or this error

Comment: Null error? That could point to something else entirely. Check @charlieftl's answer. Your data or variable have to be incorrect.

Comment: I am using IE 10 I used meta tag , do you think it is the issue

Comment: No, not at all. Run the code in the link I provided and you'll see it works perfectly. Check that `data` is in fact an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `data` is not the variable assigned to the response. Or perhaps you haven't parsed response to js array from JSON using `JSON.parse()`

Your code works fine here:

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n7C7a/)**</kbd>

Comment: I m getting : Object doesn't support property or method 'filter'

Comment: so try `console.log(data)`  ...what does that show?

Comment: I have this one  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);

Comment: ok..so you call it `obj` not `data`. That's the problem. If you are using jQuery it will parse it for you also. See my example

Comment: should I use obj.prototype.filter

Comment: no...try changing `var obj` to `var data`. You never defined a variable `data`

Comment: I am sorry none of this ways not working probably I am inexperienced about this . I tried everything you did here but still gives me error same error .Thanks for your time .